# how can I transfer Component.onCompleted:{} method from ui.qml to .qml?

Tags: qt, qml

I am developing a project by seperating ui.qml files and .qml files . So, I am writing the functionality codes(javascript codes) into .qml file and I am writing design codes in ui.qml file . However I have a problem with using Component.onComplete functionality in .qml file.

for example :

**MapDisplayForm.ui.qml**

```
Item{
   id:item1

   property alias map1

   Map{
       id: map1
       Component.OnCompleted : {
          //this is the function that i should write in Map.qml
       }
   }

}
```

---

**MapDisplay.qml**

```
MapDisplayForm{


   //it does not accept map1.oncompleted here


}
```

Comment: Am I missing a pice? `MapForm` instantiates `Map` an `Map` instantiates `MapForm`?

Comment: And what do you want to do in the `Component.OnCompleted`? Might it not be sufficient to use `Component.OnCompleted` in the Map's parent or (since that is that Item, *grandparent*)

Comment: Sorry, code was a litttle bit wrong, i just edited it. I want to use onCompleted method to choose a map type (night map or day map) according to local time

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem using the QML Connections item.
As an example in my form1.qml I have

```
SlideToAction {
    id: sosSlider
    height: 80
    Component.onCompleted: {
        if (window.getHomeLocation()) {
            normalBMargin = 0
        } else {
            normalBMargin = -80
        }
    }
}
```

To put this into the form1Form.ui.qml and form1.qml format: 
form1Form.ui.qml:

```
property alias sosSlider:sosSlider
SlideToAction {
    id: sosSlider
    height: 80
}
```

The `property alias sosSlider:sosSlider` is like saying `this property is public` and won't work otherwise.

form1.qml:

```
Connections {
    target: sosSlider
    Component.onCompleted {
        // Your code here
    }
}
```

This solved the problem for me.

I like the idea of splitting up the UI and functionality. It reminds of the MVC style that Ionic/Angular and also Django views use. It makes it really easy to play around with the UI without worrying about dependencies or other qml restrictions.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -2):

You can do something like the following:

```
Item {
   id:item1
   signal mapCompleted() // <-- custom signal
   property alias mapDisplay

   Map {
       id: map1
       Component.OnCompleted : {
          item1.mapCompleted(); // <-- emit custom signal
       }
   }
}
```

and so:

```
MapForm {
    onMapCompleted: { // <-- handle custom signal
    }
}
```

Comment: I feel like some explanation would be beneficial. Items that are supposed to be used in QML code, have to be "exported" by adding `property` keyword. This is described on this [documentation page](https://jhcnstash.global.jhcn.net/projects/NCQS/repos/quickstep/pull-requests/3167/overview), which highlights the differences between qml UI forms and regular QML code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i think i could not explain my question clearly. When i use Component.Oncompleted method in ui.qml files, the structure does not support it since it is a functionality, so i should export map1 and reach it in qml file like map1.onCompleted but i can not do it.

Answer (score -2):

UI files are meant to be used ONLY with the designer (which does not work pretty well with imperative JS). The solutions can be:

- Remove the .ui or use common .qml files
- Use an property to handle the onCompleted event and use that property in your qml file to do what you want like the next example.

**MapDisplayForm.ui.qml**

```
Item {
   id:item1
   property bool propertyOnCompleted: false

   Map {
       id: map1
       Component.onCompleted: propertyOnCompleted = true
}
```

**MapDisplay.qml**

```
MapDisplayForm {
        onPropertyOnCompletedChanged: {
        console.log("Map1 Completed")
    }
}
```