# How to use an attached property in a .qml for an object defined in a .ui.qml

Tags: qt, qml

I have the following defined in my Home.ui.qml file:

```
TextMetrics {
    id: metrics
    font: label.font
    text: label.text
}
```

Then, in the corresponding Home.qml file, I try:

```
metrics {
  Component.onCompleted: {
      console.log( "hello" );
  }
}
```

I then get the error: *Attached properties cannot be used here*

Of course, if I try:

```
TextMetrics {
    id: metrics
    font: label.font
    text: label.text
    Component.onCompleted: {
      console.log( "hello" );
    }
}
```

I get errors which say:

1. JavaScript blocks are not supported in a Qt Quick UI Form. (M223)
2. Functions are not supported in a Qt Quick UI form. (M222)

While maintaining the nice split between a .qml and .ui.qml, how can I define a Component.onCompleted for metrics?

If it matters, I am using Qt 5.12.10.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56650756/how-can-i-transfer-component-oncompleted-method-from-ui-qml-to-qml) answer your question?

Comment: yes, it does answer the question. Unfortunately, it does not have a marked answer, so apparently cannot be used as a duplicate. Plus, there is also a typo in what led me to the answer.

Comment: @JamesHudson Yes, it can be used as a duplicate since it has at least one answer with a positive score.

Comment: Sadly, the answer with a positive score has a mistake. I provided a correct answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to use Connections in the Home.qml file:

```
Connections {
  target: metrics

  Component.onCompleted: {
    console.log( "hello" );
  }
}
```